# Firebase Debug View - Discount parameter was not reflecting/displaying in Firebase DebugView

Tags: firebase, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics

I am integrating a firebase analytics logging to my app. And I am encountering issue on sending the discount item parameter.
I have no idea whether the discount value is successfully sent to the firebase because when I checked this field in the firebase debugview, it is not showing anything. I already added a currency on the item parameter but it seems still the same.

The value of the discount is added in the logs as double.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param#public-static-final-string-discount

My expectation is that the discount item parameter should be displayed in the firebase debugview.

Anyone who experienced this kind of issue?

[Sample DebugView logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWspV.jpg)

Comment: Are all your parameters and events not showing up in DebugView? Or only the discount parameter is not displayed.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT All parameters are shown in the firebase debugview, except the discount parameter.

Comment: Can you check in the Firebase console that the discount parameter is being sent correctly? I saw similar parameters not being displayed on github, you can check to see if it inspires you: ["items" param is not being shown in firebase console](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/4018)

Comment: I checked the thread and it seems my problem is different from theirs. From what I understand, the debugview is not showing any item parameters at all. 
I also checked the values of discount, I am sending it properly. I have added my sample screenshot on the post.

Comment: If you send the parameters correctly, you can report this issue to GitHub.